# Salesforce sandbox template unable to find quote object

Tags: sandbox-refresh, partial-sandbox

I am testing out the sandbox templates for my **partial** copy sandbox. And it seems that I am not able to select the Quote object to be included in this sandbox template.
Is this expected behavior? I can not seem to find any documentation on the Quote object being (automatically) included.

According to documentation; Reports, Dashboards, Products,Price books, Apps & Customizations under Setup are automatically included.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=000313358&type=1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to the Quote object of the managed package or the standard Quote object?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quote object will be included when opportunity is checked on the template and quote is dependent on opportunity.  However when it is uchecked, quote will not be included.

Check similar issue [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8SUPSA3).